# How to capture bind event of select element using formcomtrol - ReactiveFomrModule -Angular 4

Tags: angular, angular4-forms

I am using reactiveformmodule and has created a formcontrol for select tag.
On load of the page I am fetching data from backend and binding it using patchvalue to the selectformcontrol. But in doing this the change event of select is not fired.

```
 in .html
 <select id="businessType" formControlName="businessType">
                    <option value="-1">Business type</option>
                    <option *ngFor="let business of businessTypes; let i=index;" [value]="i">{{business.b_type}}</option>
                </select>

 in .ts
 this.formGroupObject.patchValue({
        'businessType': 0 //"0" is coming from backend
    })
```

I have lot of select tags across my application, so cannot capture valuechange for each selectformcontrol.

I wanted to generalize by creating a directive and adding hostlistener to it like below

```
@Directive({
selector: 'select',
})
```

and my code inside class

```
@HostListener('change', ['$event'])
onChange(event) {
    //do something
}
```

But this onChange is not fired when data is patched using form control .patchValue, when I manually select option then this is triggered.

I want to capture an event which gets triggered when the data is patched in select tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So sharing some sample code to meet your requirement which worked for me :

**Directive**

```
 import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

    @Directive({
        selector: 'select'
    })
    export class SelectDirective {
        constructor(private el: ElementRef) { 
        }

        @HostListener('change', ['$event'])
        onChange(event) {
            console.log(event);
        }

        @HostListener('ngModelChange') onNgModelChange() {
            console.log('ngModelChange');
        }

    }
```

**Module** (In which you want to use)

```
declarations: [
    SelectDirective
  ]
```

Comment: This is exactly how i have done, but the problem with this is when I Patchvalue to select formcontrol like this :this.formGroupObject.patchValue({
        'businessType': 1
    })  . Change event of select is not fired

Comment: Okay. Editing code. Check that once. Working.! Not sure how can we get value over there.

Comment: Thanks Vishw Patel, this actually worked.  I had tried the same approach earlier but I was not doing it correctly. This time it worked. Solution  mentioned below

Comment: @HostListener('ngModelChange', ['$event'])
    onNgModelChange(event: any) {
        if (event != null && event.toString() != "" && event > -1) {
            this.isSelected = true;
            return;
        }
        this.isSelected = false;
    }

Comment: I am facing another challenge in this, ngModelChange will fire when data is first attached to it and on consecutive manual change, BUT if I hide/show the form in which select tag is present, ngModelChange event is not fired. As no new data is attached, same old object is shown

Answer (score 0):

Great! I test some example here!
In your component:

```
  testForm:FormGroup;

  constructor(
    private fb: FormBuilder
  ) {
    this.testForm = this.fb.group({
      select: ['']
    })
  }

  ngOnInit(){
    this.testForm.controls.select.valueChanges.subscribe((select: string) => {
      console.log(select)
    })
  }
```

And in html:

```
 <form [formGroup]="testForm">
    <select formControlName="select" placeholder="Selecione">
      <option value="1">Test 1</option>
      <option value="2">Test 2</option>
    </select>
  </form>
```

Try that and tell me if is working!!
Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for replying. This solution will work but will be limited to one component and one form. I want to have it globally at one place, so that in future if I add more select tags, then I don't have to again subscribe to valuechange of that form