# Get select option text value - Reactive form

Tags: angular

This is my select option HTML

```
<select _ngcontent-c3=""  formcontrolname="role" value="" ng-reflect-name="role">
   <option _ngcontent-c3="" value="addrole" ng-reflect-value="addrole">--Add Role--</option>
   <option _ngcontent-c3="" value="64" ng-reflect-ng-value="64" description="user">EPS_USER</option>
   <option _ngcontent-c3="" value="65" ng-reflect-ng-value="65" description="txns">TXNS</option>
</select>
```

I need to get selected option text value instead of its value, that is if I`m selecting EPS_USER, I should get "EPS_USER" instead of 64. Form has been implemented as reactive form.

```
this.form.controls["role"].value
```

This gives 64, how to get the text?

Comment: You should share the actual code instead of the generated code from the browsers devtools.

Comment: To get select value with reactive form! try in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52928773/how-to-capture-bind-event-of-select-element-using-formcomtrol-reactivefomrmodu/52929454#52929454

Comment: can`t share the actual code because option are dynamically added from api call

Comment: Hi I want the option text i.e innerHTML, not the value, kindly help @Chiien

Answer (score 1):

Just add a attribute "label" in "option" with the value of your label and then do :

this.form.controls["role"].label

Answer (score 1):

I have found a way around, passed $event object to the method and done this..

```
populateModule = (event) => {
 let val = event.target.selectedOptions[0].innerHTML;
}
```